# ¿Como llamar a un fichero php desde una entidad de Symfony4?

Tags: php, symfony4

Me gustaría utilizar esta librería en un proyecto de Symfony4: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

El caso es que ya he utilizado esta libreria en otras ocasiones, en pequeños proyectos de php puro, sin ningún framework e incluirlo era tan sencillo como utilizar esto:

```
require 'libs/simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php';
```

El problema es que en Symfony4 no sé ni en que directorio incluir dicha carpeta ni como llamarlo. Ya he probado `require`, `require_once`, `include`, `include_once`...

Si alguien podría orientarme un poco se lo agradecería, llevo varios días con esta tontería y no consigo avanzar.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tienes dos opciones para ello.

La primera es usar un bundle externo, que utilice esa libreria. Navegando un poco en google, he encontrado este:

https://github.com/erivello/SimpleHtmlDomBundle

La segunda, que creo que es más interesante, es que symfony ya provee un componente para manipulación de dom xml y html. Es el componente domCrawler

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

Revisa en los enlaces que te he pasado. Tienen una explicación bastante clara de su uso.

Comment: Gracias, me fue de gran ayuda. Estoy ya trasteando con domCrawler y creo que me sirve para lo que quiero.